# mysql update column with value from another table with a different date format

Tags: mysql, date, woocommerce

I need to replace in the MySQL tables of a WooCommerce the value of the wp_posts.post_date_gmt field by the value of a meta field _date.

I was thinking of doing something like this (untested):

```
UPDATE wp_posts ASp
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
ON pm.post_id = p.ID
SET p.post_date_gmt = pm.meta_value
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
AND pm.meta_key = '_date'
```

The problem is that the post_date_gmt field is in date format
**2023-07-11 15:50:56** and the _date field is in the format **20230711**.

Is it possible to do this entirely in MySQL?
Or do you have to go through a PHP script that converts the date?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the **same** date format in your application? If that is not possible, `STR_TO_DATE` can help you to convert the date

Answer (score 1):

use STR_TO_DATE(string, string_format)!

```
UPDATE wp_posts ASp
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
ON pm.post_id = p.ID
SET p.post_date_gmt = str_to_date(pm.meta_value,'%Y%m%d')
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
AND pm.meta_key = '_date'
```

for usage link see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Bye